# Call controller's action from different controller in MEAN.js

Tags: javascript, mean-stack

I'm creating a game in MEAN.js and I've got an attack controller action, which is responsible for attacks evaluations. It's now called only when user open popup with military moves.

```
exports.listByUser = function(req, res) {
    Attack.find({some params}).exec(function(err, data) { 
        // some calculations
        res.json(data)
     });
}
```

I would like to call this controller action from user controller, while user sign up (sign up action). Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: It would help to see the code from your other files that you are referring to. It is typically a bad practice to call the action of one controller from a controller. FYI

Comment: @user3216673 you got a way out  of it?

Comment: I'll create almost the same function in user's controller maybe

Comment: no need of that. you can define that controller in user controller

Comment: I've made some kind of service, which provides the function to both of controllers :)